# Equivalent of PHPs -> Character in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby

I'm trying to convert a PHP script to pure Ruby code.

I have a structure like this in PHP:

```
$basic=$r->IDRequestResult->RequestResult->PersonInfo->BasicInfo;
$result['person']['FirstName']=$basic->firstname;
$result['person']['LastName']=$basic->lastname;
```

I'm stuck with this structure and `->` characters are confusing for me.

What is the equivalent of `->` character in Ruby and how can I create the similar of this structure in Ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: has any answer been helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I don't know how the rest of your Ruby port looks like, but you should end up with something along these lines if you doing a 1:1 port:

```
basic = r.IDRequestResult.RequestResult.PersonInfo.BasicInfo
result['person']['FirstName'] = basic.firstname
result['person']['LastName'] = basic.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `IDRequestResult` and others are constants:

   ```
   basic = r::IDRequestResult::RequestResult::PersonInfo::BasicInfo
   result[ 'person' ][ 'FirstName' ] = basic.firstname
   result[ 'person' ][ 'LastName' ] = basic.lastname
   ```

   **NOTE:** Don't use dots `.` for constant reference tree operations like above.
2. Or if you plan to use them as methods:

   ```
   basic = r.id_request_result.request_result.person_info.basic_info
   result[ 'person' ][ 'FirstName' ] = basic.firstname
   result[ 'person' ][ 'LastName' ] = basic.lastname
   ```